# Magento not saving any data

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have just noticed that my Magento store has stopped saving any sort of data being entered - wheter it's a Static block, product or CMS page.

Once I click SAVE or SAVE AN CONTINUE it's just loading and nothing really happens. I have tested this in all major browsers and the error occurs everywhere. Is there a way to debug this further and to determine the issue? Some expert help would be really appreciated.

I am using Magento 1.7.0.2 - no new extensions have been installed / updated recently and it just worked fine several days ago.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5199406/set-up-a-cms-page-for-magento Have you check this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @chanz - however my issue has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gowri : I get no error - it's just loading loading and nothing is happening.

Comment: check <?php phpinfo(); ?> try to increase/set your memory limit http://www.hostucan.com/webmaster-tutorials/increase-php-memory-limit